# Странная ситуация с одинаковыми экранами

Tags: java, android

Подскажите как сделать правильно...У меня 2 реальных устройства для теста, один самсунг с5 , а второй какой то китайский... Когда я работаю с текстом, то на одном экране он смотриться больше на другом меньше.

Я думал что разная плотность экранов и создал папки `ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi` и начал тестировать какая папка для какого устройства будет определяться системой. Конечно в каждую вложил такие `dimen` ресурсы

```
<resources>
<dimen name="activity_header_button_size">14sp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_text_size">8sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Сначала подключил китайца и изменил размеры в папке для самой маленькой плотности `ldpi` на

```
<resources>
<dimen name="activity_header_button_size">20sp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_text_size">14sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Ничего не поменялось... я все вернул в исходное состояние и продолжил повозрастающе менять в каждой папке и методом научного тыка определил, что этот китайский девайс реагирует когда я меняю размер в папке

```
xxhdpi
```

И все, только на нее.

Я подключил самсунг и начал делать тоже самое и мое удивление было когда я определил, что он тоже реагирует только на эту папку `xxhdpi`

**Но почему тогда если система определяет плотности их экранов как одинаковые, размеры на них смотрятся совсем не одинаково??**

Когда я устанавливаю в этой папке `xxhdpi` вот такие размеры

```
<resources>
<dimen name="activity_header_button_size">20sp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_text_size">14sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**То на китайце получаю вот такую картинку**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**А на самсунге вот такую**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно, что на китайский девайс нужно установить меньшие размеры чтоб получить ожидаемый результат, **но как это сделать если система определяет для них одну и туже ресурсную папку?**

Comment: Какие разрешения и физические размеры экрана обоих девайсов?
Возможно, стоит найти то что отличается у китайца, и сделать уникальную папку (sw<N>dp, large итд):

http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Comment: Выключите для китайка увеличенный размер шрифтов в настройках его экрана. Либо используйте dp вместо sp если не хотите поддерживать увеличенные размеры шрифтов.

Comment: @xkor Да действительно, я даже не знал, что есть такая возможность...  Но скажите, если я правильно понял, то чтоб в дальнейшем избегать такой ситуации когда увеличение стоит на уровне девайса я могу устанавливать размеры в `dp` и они не будут увеличиваться?

Comment: Да, именно этим dp от sp  и отличается